# Crossfilter reduce functions

Tags: javascript, crossfilter

I want to understand how the reduce functions are used in Crossfilter. Namely, the

```
reduceAdd(p,v){...}
reduceRemove(p,v){...}
```

and

```
reduceInitial(p,v){...}
```

in

```
group.reduce(reduceAdd, reduceRemove, reduceInitial);
```

From [Crossfilter's API reference](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#group_reduce), I understand that the `p` and `v` arguments represent the group and dimension value respectively.

From what I understand, the return value of the reduce functions determine what the groupValue should be changed to after the element is added or removed from the group. Is this correct?

Also, what is the reduceInitial function for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct, if you substitute "bin value" for "groupValue" in what you wrote.

A group is made of an array of bins; each bin is a key-value pair. For every group, all rows of the data supplied to crossfilter will "fall into" one bin or another. The reduce functions determine what happens when a row falls into a bin, or is removed from it because the filters changed.

Crossfilter determines which bin any row falls into by using using the [dimension value accessor](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#dimension) and the [group value function](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#dimension_group).

#### When are reduction functions called?

When a crossfilter initializes a new group, it **adds** all the currently matching rows of the data to all the groups. The group determines a *key* for each row by using the dimension value accessor and the group value function. Then it looks up the bin using that key, and applies the `reduceAdd` function to the previous bin value and the row data to produce the new bin value.

When any filter on any dimension of the crossfilter changes value, some rows will stop matching and some rows will start matching the new set of filters. The rows that stop matching are **removed** from the matching bin using the `reduceRemove` function, and the rows that start matching are **added** using the `reduceAdd` function.

When a row is added, some groups may not already have a bin which matches the key for that row. At that point a new bin must be **initialized** and at that point the group calls `reduceInitial` to get the user-specified blank value for the bins of that group.

#### Crossfilter's group.reduce compared to Array.reduce

The `reduceAdd` and `reduceRemove` functions are similar to the functions you would pass to Javascript's [Array.reduce function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). The first parameter `p` takes the previous value of the bin, and the second paramter `v` takes the current row data being considered.

In contrast to `Array.reduce`, in `group.reduce`

- values can be removed as well as added
- the initial value is produced by the `reduceInitial` function instead of being passed to `reduce`
- it doesn't perform the aggregation immediately; instead you are supplying functions that will get called whenever filters change or data is added or removed

Comment: What *initial value* are you referring to? Up to this point I only understand that if a filter is applied and a certain row is filtered out, the reduce.Remove function will determine how the groupValue will change. Furthermore, when is the reduce.Add function used, i.e. what do we mean by filtering a row *in*?

Comment: I've added a substantial introduction above.

Comment: *When a row is added, some groups may not already have a bin which matches the key for that row. At that point a new bin must be initialized and at that point the group calls reduceInitial to get the user-specified blank value for the bins of that group.*
Why is there a necessity for a new bin to be initialized; i.e. in what situation would it be insufficient to just use the first row to be added for initialization?

Comment: It's just like with `Array.reduce`: the reduce function takes two inputs. You wouldn't want to sometimes see null for the first input, just because this is the first value which has been added to the bin. Instead, `reduceInitial` is called to produce the blank value.