# complex reduce sample unclear how the reduce works

Tags: crossfilter

Starting with [complex reduce sample](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/examples/complex-reduce.html)
I have trimmed it down to a single chart and I am trying to understand how the reduce works

I have made comments in the code that were not in the example denoting what I think is happening based on how I read the docs.

```
function groupArrayAdd(keyfn) {
      var bisect = d3.bisector(keyfn);  //set the bisector value function
     //elements is the group that we are reducing,item is the current item
       //this is a the reduce function being supplied to the reduce call on the group runAvgGroup for add below
      return function(elements, item) {
          //get the position of the key value  for this element in the sorted array and put it there
          var pos = bisect.right(elements, keyfn(item));
          elements.splice(pos, 0, item);
          return elements;
      };
  }
  function groupArrayRemove(keyfn) {
      var bisect = d3.bisector(keyfn);//set the bisector value function
    //elements is the group that we are reducing,item is the current item
    //this is a the reduce function being supplied to the reduce call on the group runAvgGroup for remove below
      return function(elements, item) {
        //get the position of the key value  for this element in the sorted array and splice it out
          var pos = bisect.left(elements, keyfn(item));
          if(keyfn(elements[pos])===keyfn(item))
              elements.splice(pos, 1);
          return elements;
      };
  }
  function groupArrayInit() {
                  //for each key found by the key function return this array?
      return [];  //the result array for where the data is being inserted in sorted order?
  }
```

I am not quite sure my perception of how this is working is quite right. Some of the magic isn't showing itself. Am I correct that elements is the group the reduce function is being called on ? also the array in groupArrayInit() how is it being indirectly populated?

Part of me feels that the functions supplied to the reduce call are really array.map functions not array.reduce functions but I just can't quite put my finger on why. having read the docs I am just not making a connection here.

Any help would be appreciated.
Also have I missed Pens/Fiddles that are created for all these examples? like this one
http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/complex-reduce.html which is where I started with this but had to download the csv and manually convert to Json.

--------------Update
I added some print statements to try to clarify how the add function is working

```
  function groupArrayAdd(keyfn) {
      var bisect = d3.bisector(keyfn);  //set the bisector value function
     //elements is the group that we are reducing,item is the current item
       //this is a the reduce function being supplied to the reduce call on the group runAvgGroup for add below
      return function(elements, item) {
        console.log("---Start Elements and Item and keyfn(item)----")
        console.log(elements)  //elements grouped by run?
        console.log(item)   //not seeing the pattern on what this is on each run
        console.log(keyfn(item))
        console.log("---End----")
          //get the position of the key value  for this element in the sorted array and put it there
          var pos = bisect.right(elements, keyfn(item));
          elements.splice(pos, 0, item);
          return elements;
      };
  }
```

and to print out the group's contents

```
console.log("RunAvgGroup")
console.log(runAvgGroup.top(Infinity))
```

which results in 
[image: final group not sorted by Key]

Which appears to be incorrect b/c the values are not sorted by key (the run number)?
And looking at the results of the print statements doesn't seem to help either.

Answer (score 1):

This looks basically right to me. The issues are just conceptual.

Crossfilter’s group.reduce is not exactly like either Array.reduce or Array.map. Group.reduce defines methods for handling adding new records to a group or removing records from a group. So it is conceptually similar to an incremental Array.reduce that supports an reversal operation. This allows filters to be applied and removed.

Group.top returns your list of groups. The value property of these groups should be the elements value that your reduce functions return. The key of the group is the value returned by your group accessor (defined in the dimension.group call that creates your group) or your dimension accessor if you didn’t define a group accessor. Reduce functions work only on the group values and do not have direct access to the group key.

So check those values in the group.top output and hopefully you’ll see the lists of elements you expect.

Comment: i found that the [] in the init is being used as the initial value from another post  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47834652/crossfilter-reduce-functions?rq=1 and I have added more comments and prints to the fiddle indicating how the result groups are not sorted the way I would expect. Part of the issue is the dimension the group is on is the run dimension but the grouping is by experiment.. Thank for the comment

Comment: https://codepen.io/rdavi10471a2/full/yxoGgj/  is the PEN I mentioned that I created from the sample. forgot to add it.

Comment: The results groups aren’t what you’re dealing with in the reduce functions though. The arrays in the value property of each group are. I’ll try to take a look at the example you put together tomorrow, but could you perhaps explain a little more about what you are expecting and how that differs from what you are seeing?

Comment: I was just trying to understand how things work inside the reduce from an input to output and as far as I could tell runDimension.group() was being passed to each of the reduce functions to be further transformed to extract each experiments runs into new groups but for the life of me I can't *see* how that is happening from my log statements.I can see each iteration appears to remove one experiment but where it goes and how it ends up in a new group is the magic I was trying to understand. I was almost to the point to add the implied params to reduce (current index) and see what would happen.

Comment: Also I am perplexed as to why the output is not sorted by key.. it usually is when you console.log(runAvgGroup.top(Infinity))

Comment: runDimension.group().all()  is sorted and value is the count of the items in the group runDimension.group().top(Infinty) should be the same but it is not sorted run(1) is last. RunAvgGroup makes the desired output arrays but again run(1) is last in the list.

Comment: Group.top sorts by the value property of the group by default. The output of runDimension.group() is not passed to each reducer. Groups are built for each key in the dimension. The value of the group is initialized by reduceInit and then updated by the add/remove functions as records are added and removed. The objects available in the group are the value of the group (which can be an object) and the record being added or removed. I’d recommend if you are working on understanding how groups work, you start with one of the simpler examples of custom reducers or a Crossfilter tutorial.

Comment: Understood. I have written my own reducer before but not one that kept its own copies of the rows-- so I was looking at how that worked via this sample. the missing part is what is being passed to each reducer and why it looks like it is iterating over each individual array but returning the full array.

Comment: `group.top(N)` has no meaning in this example unless you specify [group.order()](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#group_order). The values are arrays, and ordering is not very meaningful for arrays. (They are coerced to strings first.)

Comment: Gordon, figured it was something like that .. actually i was ready to blame bisect.right because all the groups have the same number of items (5)

Comment: fell victium to this https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2408-chrome-dev-tools-live-update-in-the-javascript-console-is-confusing.htm